# how to say "same class" in a Swift generic

Tags: generics, swift

If a Swift generic type constraint is a protocol name, I can require that two types, constrained to that protocol, be the same type. For example:

```
protocol Flier {}
struct Bird : Flier {}
struct Insect: Flier {}
func flockTwoTogether<T:Flier>(f1:T, f2:T) {}
```

The function `flockTwoTogether` can be called with a Bird and a Bird or with an Insect and an Insect, but not with a Bird and an Insect. That is the limitation I want. So far, so good.

However, if I try the same thing with a class name, it doesn't work:

```
class Dog {}
class NoisyDog : Dog {}
class WellBehavedDog: Dog {}
func walkTwoTogether<T:Dog>(d1:T, d2:T) {}
```

The problem is that I can call `walkTwoTogether` with a WellBehavedDog and a NoisyDog. This is what I want to prevent.

There are really two questions here:

- Is there a way to say that `walkTwoTogether` can't be called with a WellBehavedDog and a NoisyDog?
- Is this a bug? I ask because if I can't use a generic to say this, it is hard to see why it is useful for a generic constraint to be a class name at all, since we could get the same result just with a normal function.

Comment: This seems like expected behaviour to me? You've constrained the optional to be of type Dog. both of your subclasses conform to that type, and nothing in the declaration constrains them. If there was a way to do what you want I would expect it to require a `where` clause, as in `<T:Dog, U:Dog where T.Type == U.Type>`, but that also throws an error.

Comment: @cmyr Yes, of course I tried that. That's why I asked if what I'm doing is not how to do it, is it possible to do it. :)

Comment: It all works if `Dog` is a protocol. Generic constraints can't be enforced on non-protocol types. *(something something Type Erasure)*

Comment: @mattt That's why I'm curious why T:SomeClass is allowed. The docs explicitly say you can do this, but I don't get why it's useful. I mean, if it doesn't enforce anything, what's it for? If I wanted any two Dog subclasses to be allowed to walk together, I could just use a nongeneric function.

Comment: @matt Perhaps for additional protocol generic constraints? `protocol GoodBoy {}; extension WellBehavedDog: GoodBoy {}; func walkTwoTogether<T: Dog where T: GoodBoy>(d1: T, d2: T) {}`

Comment: But you're right, this is something that would be interesting and useful to be further documented.

Comment: Documenting it is what I am trying to do. :)

Comment: It looks like you're talking to yourself, matt(t). :)

Comment: I wonder if this changed at all in Swift3

Answer (score 3):

*Not an answer, per se, but some more data perhaps...* The problem is when you call:

```
walkTwoTogether(NoisyDog(), WellBehavedDog())
```

Swift can just treat both instances as if they're instances of `Dog` (aka, upcast) — we need that so we can call methods meant for class `A` with subclasses of `A`. (I know you know this.)

Swift doesn't upcast to protocols, so the only way to do it is to specify a protocol for the subclasses that the superclass *doesn't* conform to:

```
protocol Walkable {}
extension NoisyDog : Walkable {}
extension WellBehavedDog: Walkable {}
func walkTwoTogether<T: Dog where T: Walkable>(d1:T, d2:T) { }

walkTwoTogether(NoisyDog(), WellBehavedDog())
// error: type 'Dog' does not conform to protocol 'Walkable'
```

The error message explicitly shows what is going on — the only way to call this version of `walkToTogether` is to upcast the subclass instances to `Dog`, but `Dog` doesn't conform to `Walkable`.

Comment: It's lucky, then, that I didn't present the problem as I originally posed it to myself, which was to distinguish Dog from NoisyDog!

Comment: No subclasses allowed!

Answer (score 1):

I would say that this should be considered a bug since `inout` parameters change the type requirements as they should be:

```
func walkTwoTogether<T:Dog>(inout d1:T, d2:T) {
```

Now it has the expected behavior where you can only pass two values of the same type. (Tested in Swift 1.2 and Swift 2 beta 5)

Comment: Yes and no. This is legal: `var d : Dog = WellBehavedDog(); walkTwoTogether(&d, NoisyDog())` And in any case, if there's a bug, I think the most we can say is that it's the inconsistency; it's unclear _which_ is right.

Comment: @matt Your are right it could be either one. In your case you have to mark both parameters with `inout`. Interestingly it behaves almost the same if you don't use a generic constraint.

Comment: I'm more puzzled than ever! But your datum is darned interesting, there's no doubt of that.