# Use Self as generic type

Tags: generics, swift

`Self` can be used as the return type of a method:

```
func doSomething() -> Self {}
```

Is it somehow possible to use `Self` as a generic type like this?

```
func doSomething() -> Wrapper<Self> {}
```

**Example**

It would be nice if I could subclass ChristmasPresent and let it have a `wrapped` function that returns a WrappedPresent with the generic set to whatever the subclass was.

```
class ChristmasPresent {
    func wrapped() -> WrappedPresent<Self> {
        return WrappedPresent(present: self)
    }
}

class WrappedPresent<T: ChristmasPresent> {
    var present: T

    init(present: T) {
        self.present = present
    }
}

class ToyCar: ChristmasPresent {}

let wrappedToyCar = ToyCar().wrapped() // Inferred to be: WrappedPresent<ToyCar>
```

Comment: What would this constraint represent? Where is this generic constraint registered? How is Wrapper declared? If it's `Wrapper<T: class>`, we can return `Wrapper<self.dynamicType>`, maybe..

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't know the type of "Self" at the time? Maybe I'm just not thinking hard enough. You can always replace "Self" with the actual class name

Comment: I've added an example :).

Comment: @Rengers I may be wrong, but I have a feeling that my question here is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27323165/how-to-say-same-class-in-a-swift-generic Generics do not handle class-and-subclass in quite the way you would expect. This is probably because they were designed to accomplish the work of struct-and-protocol that they do in fact accomplish.

Comment: Here's an interesting sidelight. I can make Swift generate an error message "'Self' is only available in a protocol or as the result of a class method." But it is also available as the result of an instance method - though maybe "class method" here means "a method of a class", not a "class method" as opposed to an "instance method". I think I'll file a bug on this.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The most vexing paradox in Swift is this: "Swift prefers methods, but Swift's functions are more powerful." The Swift team knows that, and someday I am certain we will have powerful methods. But today is not that day. There are many things you'd like to express in methods that you cannot. Everything you want can be done easily with functions, however.

```
class ChristmasPresent {}

struct WrappedPresent<T: ChristmasPresent> {
    let present: T
}

func wrap<T:ChristmasPresent>(present: T) -> WrappedPresent<T> {
    return WrappedPresent(present: present);
}

class ToyCar: ChristmasPresent {}

let wrappedToyCar = wrap(ToyCar()) // Inferred to be: WrappedPresent<ToyCar>
```

Note that if your code *did* compile, you might still be quite surprised at the result. [Swift custom types are not covariant](http://nomothetis.svbtle.com/type-variance-in-swift), so a `WrappedPresent<ToyCar>` is not a subtype of `WrappedPresent<ChristmasPresent>`. So if you had an array of wrapped presents, you could not put a wrapped toycar in it. That could easily force you back to just using a fixed (non-type-parameterized) `WrappedPresent` type anyway, making the question moot. Generics and classes do not always mix as well as you might imagine in Swift.

If you have a practical example of a problem you'd want to solve with this, then I do recommend bringing it up on the dev forums. The Swift team is very responsive.

Comment: Ah of course, it never crossed my mind that this was solvable with functions! Still thinking in an Objective-C mindset too much :).